# Indeterministic final measurements simulating quantum torus code in Stim

Tags: surface-code, stim

I am trying to simulate the quantum torus code in Stim but have indeterministic errors when I do the final measurements and compare data qubits with respective previous syndrome qubit measurements.

I can't find the bug. Due to the bug, I understand that the measured qubits are not on a computational basis. However, due to the way the detectors are constructed, considering the qubits in the plaquettes, I can't find a reason for the bug.

See the circuit that I generate below.

```
QUBIT_COORDS(0, 1) 0                                                                                                                 
QUBIT_COORDS(0, 3) 1                                                                                                                 
QUBIT_COORDS(0, 5) 2                                                                                                                 
QUBIT_COORDS(1, 0) 3                                                                                                                 
QUBIT_COORDS(1, 2) 4                                                                                                                 
QUBIT_COORDS(1, 4) 5                                                                                                                 
QUBIT_COORDS(2, 1) 6                                                                                                                 
QUBIT_COORDS(2, 3) 7                                                                                                                 
QUBIT_COORDS(2, 5) 8                                                                                                                 
QUBIT_COORDS(3, 0) 9                                                                                                                 
QUBIT_COORDS(3, 2) 10                                                                                                                
QUBIT_COORDS(3, 4) 11                                                                                                                
QUBIT_COORDS(4, 1) 12                                                                                                                
QUBIT_COORDS(4, 3) 13                                                                                                                
QUBIT_COORDS(4, 5) 14                                                                                                                
QUBIT_COORDS(5, 0) 15                                                                                                                
QUBIT_COORDS(5, 2) 16                                                                                                                
QUBIT_COORDS(5, 4) 17                                                                                                                
H 6 1 13 8                                                                                                                           
CX 6 10 1 5 13 17 8 9 4 0 16 12 11 7 3 2 15 14                                                                                       
TICK                                                                                                                                 
CX 6 4 1 17 13 11 8 3 16 0 10 12 5 7 15 2 9 14                                                                                       
TICK                                                                                                                                 
CX 6 3 1 16 13 10 8 5 15 0 9 12 4 7 17 2 11 14                                                                                       
TICK                                                                                                                                 
CX 6 9 1 4 13 16 8 11 3 0 15 12 10 7 5 2 17 14                                                                                       
TICK                                                                                                                                 
DEPOLARIZE2(0) 6 10 1 5 13 17 8 9 6 4 1 17 13 11 8 3 6 3 1 16 13 10 8 5 6 9 1 4 13 16 8 11 0 4 12 16 7 11 2 3 14 15 0 16 12 10 7 5 2 
15 14 9 0 15 12 9 7 4 2 17 14 11 0 3 12 15 7 10 2 5 14 17                                                                            
MR 6 1 13 8 0 12 7 2 14                                                                                                              
CX 6 10 1 5 13 17 8 9 4 0 16 12 11 7 3 2 15 14                                                                                       
TICK                                                                                                                                 
CX 6 4 1 17 13 11 8 3 16 0 10 12 5 7 15 2 9 14                                                                                       
TICK                                                                                                                                 
CX 6 3 1 16 13 10 8 5 15 0 9 12 4 7 17 2 11 14                                                                                       
TICK                                                                                                                                 
CX 6 9 1 4 13 16 8 11 3 0 15 12 10 7 5 2 17 14                                                                                       
TICK                                                                                                                                 
H 6 1 13 8 6 1 13 8                                                                                                                  
CX 6 10 1 5 13 17 8 9 4 0 16 12 11 7 3 2 15 14                                                                                       
TICK                                                                                                                                 
CX 6 4 1 17 13 11 8 3 16 0 10 12 5 7 15 2 9 14                                                                                       
TICK                                                                                                                                 
CX 6 3 1 16 13 10 8 5 15 0 9 12 4 7 17 2 11 14                                                                                       
TICK                                                                                                                                 
CX 6 9 1 4 13 16 8 11 3 0 15 12 10 7 5 2 17 14                                                                                       
TICK                                                                                                                                 
DEPOLARIZE2(0) 6 10 1 5 13 17 8 9 6 4 1 17 13 11 8 3 6 3 1 16 13 10 8 5 6 9 1 4 13 16 8 11 0 4 12 16 7 11 2 3 14 15 0 16 12 10 7 5 2 
15 14 9 0 15 12 9 7 4 2 17 14 11 0 3 12 15 7 10 2 5 14 17                                                                            
MR 6 1 13 8 0 12 7 2 14                                                                                                              
CX 6 10 1 5 13 17 8 9 4 0 16 12 11 7 3 2 15 14                                                                                       
TICK                                                                                                                                 
CX 6 4 1 17 13 11 8 3 16 0 10 12 5 7 15 2 9 14                                                                                       
TICK                                                                                                                                 
CX 6 3 1 16 13 10 8 5 15 0 9 12 4 7 17 2 11 14                                                                                       
TICK                                                                                                                                 
CX 6 9 1 4 13 16 8 11 3 0 15 12 10 7 5 2 17 14                                                                                       
TICK                                                                                                                                 
H 6 1 13 8                                                                                                                           
DETECTOR(0, 1, 0) rec[-5]                                                                                                            
DETECTOR(4, 1, 0) rec[-4]                                                                                                            
DETECTOR(2, 3, 0) rec[-3]                                                                                                            
DETECTOR(0, 5, 0) rec[-2]                                                                                                            
DETECTOR(4, 5, 0) rec[-1]                                                                                                            
REPEAT 10 {                                                                                                                          
    H 6 1 13 8                                                                                                                       
    CX 6 10 1 5 13 17 8 9 4 0 16 12 11 7 3 2 15 14                                                                                   
    TICK                                                                                                                             
    CX 6 4 1 17 13 11 8 3 16 0 10 12 5 7 15 2 9 14                                                                                   
    TICK                                                                                                                             
    CX 6 3 1 16 13 10 8 5 15 0 9 12 4 7 17 2 11 14                                                                                   
    TICK                                                                                                                             
    CX 6 9 1 4 13 16 8 11 3 0 15 12 10 7 5 2 17 14                                                                                   
    TICK                                                                                                                             
    DEPOLARIZE2(0) 6 10 1 5 13 17 8 9 6 4 1 17 13 11 8 3 6 3 1 16 13 10 8 5 6 9 1 4 13 16 8 11 0 4 12 16 7 11 2 3 14 15 0 16 12 10 7 
5 2 15 14 9 0 15 12 9 7 4 2 17 14 11 0 3 12 15 7 10 2 5 14 17                                                                        
    MR 6 1 13 8 0 12 7 2 14                                                                                                          
    CX 6 10 1 5 13 17 8 9 4 0 16 12 11 7 3 2 15 14                                                                                   
    TICK                                                                                                                             
    CX 6 4 1 17 13 11 8 3 16 0 10 12 5 7 15 2 9 14                                                                                   
    TICK                                                                                                                             
    CX 6 3 1 16 13 10 8 5 15 0 9 12 4 7 17 2 11 14                                                                                   
    TICK                                                                                                                             
    CX 6 9 1 4 13 16 8 11 3 0 15 12 10 7 5 2 17 14                                                                                   
    TICK                                                                                                                             
    H 6 1 13 8                                                                                                                       
    SHIFT_COORDS(0, 0, 1)                                                                                                            
    DETECTOR(0, 1, 0) rec[-5] rec[-14]                                                                                               
    DETECTOR(4, 1, 0) rec[-4] rec[-13]                                                                                               
    DETECTOR(2, 3, 0) rec[-3] rec[-12]                                                                                               
    DETECTOR(0, 5, 0) rec[-2] rec[-11]                                                                                               
    DETECTOR(4, 5, 0) rec[-1] rec[-10]                                                                                               
    DETECTOR(2, 1, 0) rec[-9] rec[-18]                                                                                               
    DETECTOR(0, 3, 0) rec[-8] rec[-17]                                                                                               
    DETECTOR(4, 3, 0) rec[-7] rec[-16]                                                                                               
    DETECTOR(2, 5, 0) rec[-6] rec[-15]                                                                                               
}                                                                                                                                    
M 3 9 15 4 10 16 5 11 17                                                                                                             
DETECTOR(0, 1, 1) rec[-9] rec[-7] rec[-6] rec[-4] rec[-14]                                                                           
DETECTOR(4, 1, 1) rec[-8] rec[-7] rec[-5] rec[-4] rec[-13]                                                                           
DETECTOR(2, 3, 1) rec[-6] rec[-5] rec[-3] rec[-2] rec[-12]                                                                           
DETECTOR(0, 5, 1) rec[-9] rec[-7] rec[-3] rec[-1] rec[-11]                                                                           
DETECTOR(4, 5, 1) rec[-8] rec[-7] rec[-2] rec[-1] rec[-10]                                                                           
OBSERVABLE_INCLUDE(0) rec[-9] rec[-8] rec[-7]
```

Answer (score 1):

This circuit has quite a few problems, the data measurements being non-deterministic is just the one that's being noticed first.

For example, if you install the dev version of stim and make a detector slice diagram, you should see blue (Z) and red (X) shapes growing from a point then shrinking back down. Instead, you only see blue shapes with some of them not expanding:

[image]

Looking at it more in depth it looks like you're missing every other layer of measurements, and also like your X basis stabilizer measurement qubits are initialized in the wrong basis resulting in their later measurement not depending on the intended stabilizer:

[image]

I also noticed that some Z errors at resets propagate to multiple measurements instead, but typically they would only propagate to one:

[image]

You almost definitely need to fix these things before you will be able to fix the failures at the end of the circuit.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Craig. I can see the stupid thing I did.

I think to have solved the problem above by placing the Hadamard gate before measurements, which makes complete sense, and initializing X-syndrome qubits with RX and measuring via MRX. However, I really don't understand why initializing them with R gate and measuring with MR does not work.

I would love it if you could make sense of such a thing.

Comment: @Unknown If you're trying to do the cycle with CNOTs you should be initializing the Z measure qubits with RX (or R then H) and the X measure qubits with R. Otherwise the part of the CNOT on the measure qubit will commute with the initialization basis and do nothing (e.g. CNOT controlled by |0> does nothing).